How to decrypt a key encrypted using the sodium R package in python?
I have he following R functions that use the sodium R package to encrypt and decrypt an access key with a password:
encrypt_access_key <- function(access_key, password) {
  key <- sha256(charToRaw(password))
  nonce <- random(24)  # Generate a random nonce
  encrypted <- data_encrypt(charToRaw(access_key), key, nonce)
  list(
    encrypted_access_key = base64encode(encrypted),
    nonce = base64encode(nonce)
  )
}

decrypt_access_key <- function(encrypted_access_key, nonce, password) {
  key <- sha256(charToRaw(password))
  encrypted_raw <- base64decode(encrypted_access_key)
  nonce_raw <- base64decode(nonce)
  rawToChar(data_decrypt(encrypted_raw, key, nonce_raw))
} 

I want to create a python function that mimics the functionality of the decrypt_access_key function, but I have not been able to do so... In case it is useful, here is the documentation for the data_encrypt and data_decrypt functions from the sodium package: link
Edit: Here is a reproducible example
encripted_message <- encrypt_access_key("This is a hidden message", "Example123")

decrypt_access_key(encripted_message$encrypted_access_key, encripted_message$nonce, "Example123")

There is no need to replicate the functionality of encrypt_access_key, all I need is a python function that can get the string stored as encripted_message$encrypted_access_key and decrypt the message
Edit 2: Here is the reproductible example with the explicit value of the nonce and the encrypted message
decrypt_access_key(encrypted_access_key = "QG42J4fSVcY9luHaXiEhQcR85isjgUlmFc97pMHIIwuxQyZzDNpz2w==", nonce = "LpO7fBaCs1iobxDxVmOPFycTe/BCifqh", password = "Example123")

And here is one of the failed attempts to decrypt the message using python:
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import ChaCha20_Poly1305
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
import hashlib

def decrypt_access_key(encrypted_access_key, nonce, password):
    # Decode the base64 encoded components
    encrypted_access_key_bytes = base64.b64decode(encrypted_access_key)
    nonce_bytes = base64.b64decode(nonce)
    
    # Derive the key using PBKDF2
    key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode(), b'', 100000)
    
    # Decrypt the access key using ChaCha20-Poly1305
    cipher = ChaCha20_Poly1305.new(key=key, nonce=nonce_bytes)
    decrypted = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_access_key_bytes)
    
    return decrypted.decode('utf-8')

# Example usage
encrypted_access_key = 'QG42J4fSVcY9luHaXiEhQcR85isjgUlmFc97pMHIIwuxQyZzDNpz2w=='
nonce = 'LpO7fBaCs1iobxDxVmOPFycTe/BCifqh'
password = 'Example123'

decrypted_access_key = decrypt_access_key(encrypted_access_key, nonce, password)
print(decrypted_access_key)


Post non-productive test data: key, plaintext and ciphertext generated by the R code, and your most recent Python code.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's not clear what exactly you are passing to these function. What output have you gotten from your python code?

@MrFlick I've added a reproducible example! My python code is not worth sharing, because it is just failed attempts of chatGPT to understand how sodium encrypts the message

The ciphertext and nonce are missing in your example. These are needed for the test of the Python decryption function! Also, SO is not a code delivery service. You should therefore post your Python code, and also specify which Python library should be used.

You can see the encoded nonce by printing encripted_message$nonce in R, but give me a sec and I will enter the explicit string in the example. I really don't know which python library should be used, but still I will add one of chatgpts failed attempts in python

The R code for encryption derives the key from a password using SHA256 and performs authenticated encryption with SecretBox, which uses XSalsa20 and Poly1305 under the hood, see here. The result returns the (24 bytes) nonce and the concatenation of ciphertext and (16 bytes) tag separately.
The posted Python code is not compatible with SecretBox.
A possible NaCl/Libsodium Python port that supports SecretBox is PyNaCl. In contrast to the R library, PyNaCl returns the concatenation of nonce, ciphertext and tag as the result of the encryption, and requires the concatenation of nonce, ciphertext and tag during decryption:
import nacl.secret
import hashlib
import base64

key = hashlib.sha256(b'Example123').digest()
box = nacl.secret.SecretBox(key)

nonceB64 = 'LpO7fBaCs1iobxDxVmOPFycTe/BCifqh'
ciphertextTagB64 = 'QG42J4fSVcY9luHaXiEhQcR85isjgUlmFc97pMHIIwuxQyZzDNpz2w=='

nonceCiphertextTag = base64.b64decode(nonceB64) + base64.b64decode(ciphertextTagB64)
decrypted = box.decrypt(nonceCiphertextTag)
print(decrypted.decode('utf-8')) # This is a hidden message


Note that the use of a fast digest such as SHA256 is a vulnerability. It is more secure to use a reliable key derivation function, at least PBKDF2, or even better the more modern algorithms mentioned in the Libsodium documentation (Argon2, Scrypt), see here.

The following Python function decrypts an access key that was encrypted using the sodium package in R. This function aligns with the encryption and decryption processes used in R, ensuring compatibility with the XSalsa20-Poly1305 algorithm employed by the SecretBox method from the PyNaCl library. This emphasises maintaining the same key derivation method (SHA256) as used in the R implementation and concatenates the nonce and ciphertext as required by PyNaCl. This should ensure that the decryption process mirrors the encryption process exactly, guaranteeing the correct retrieval of the original message.
import base64
from nacl.secret import SecretBox
import hashlib

def decrypt_access_key(encrypted_access_key, nonce, password):
    # Decode the base64 encoded components
    encrypted_access_key_bytes = base64.b64decode(encrypted_access_key)
    nonce_bytes = base64.b64decode(nonce)
    
    # Derive the key using SHA256 (to match the R implementation)
    key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).digest()
    
    # Create a SecretBox with the derived key
    box = SecretBox(key)
    
    # Concatenate nonce and encrypted access key
    nonce_ciphertext = nonce_bytes + encrypted_access_key_bytes
    
    # Decrypt the access key
    decrypted = box.decrypt(nonce_ciphertext)
    
    return decrypted.decode('utf-8')

# Example usage
encrypted_access_key = 'QG42J4fSVcY9luHaXiEhQcR85isjgUlmFc97pMHIIwuxQyZzDNpz2w=='
nonce = 'LpO7fBaCs1iobxDxVmOPFycTe/BCifqh'
password = 'Example123'

decrypted_access_key = decrypt_access_key(encrypted_access_key, nonce, password)
print(decrypted_access_key)  # This is a hidden message

Explanation
This function aligns with the encryption and decryption processes used in R, ensuring compatibility with the XSalsa20-Poly1305 algorithm employed by the SecretBox method from the PyNaCl library. Here  I tried to emphasise maintaining the same key derivation method (SHA256) as used in the R implementation and concatenates the nonce and ciphertext as required by PyNaCl. This ensures that the decryption process mirrors the encryption process exactly, guaranteeing the correct retrieval of the original message.
encrypted_access_key and nonce are base64 decoded to convert them back to their original byte format. The key is derived using SHA256 to match the key derivation method used in the R code (sha256(charToRaw(password))). A SecretBox object is created with the derived key, providing the methods for encryption and decryption using the XSalsa20-Poly1305 scheme. The nonce and the encrypted access key are concatenated, as PyNaCl requires the nonce to be prefixed to the ciphertext for decryption. The decrypt method of the SecretBox object is then used to decrypt the concatenated nonce and encrypted access key. The result is decoded from bytes to a UTF-8-encoded string, yielding the original message. This Python function should now correctly decrypt the message encrypted with the sodium R package, maintaining consistency with the encryption and decryption methods used in R.
